# Java - Stop execution and resume later

Tags: java

I have a program that takes a lot of time to execute and I would like to know the best way to stop it and resume later (saving all the info already calculated) - eg: shutdown PC and resume the execution in the next day.

The program itself is a kind-of brute force calculation to know the best path along several cities,

Thank you.

Comment: How about writing your interim results to files and reading them before continuing?

Comment: You need to find a way to serialize your data. Some way to save it to a file. The quickest and dirtiest is to use Serialization. It is often recommended not to use Serialize, but it is pretty easy. Maybe you can include in your example the class with data you need to save.

Comment: You could run that program in a virtual machine to stop and resume it.

Comment: What would be the best approach besides the serialization?

Comment: @ruigomes You need to include your class that has the data. There isn't necessarily a best fit for every situation.